# I have a bug in the library Html2Canvas - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, html2canvas

I want to make a screenshot on the google maps map. I implement the code, by default, of the library and I get the following error by console. **Uncaught (in promise) Provided element is not within a Document**. He tried to implement a promise with .then, but it does not work either. I do not know if the problem is understood.

I leave the code here below

```
HTML

<template>
  <div>
    <div ref="printMe">
      <h1>Print me!</h1>
    </div>
    <img :src="output">
  </div>
<template>

COMPONENT.VUE

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      output: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async print() {
      const el = this.$refs.printMe;
      const options = {
        type: 'dataURL'
      }
      this.output = await this.$html2canvas(el, options);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I show a bug **Uncaught (in promise) Provided element is not within a Document**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a template error that stops the Vue renderer `</template>`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div ref="printMe">
      <h1>Print me!</h1>
    </div>
    <img :src="output">
  </div>
</template>
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/x7oozwk24)

Comment: thanks for you answer. But I still don´t see the fault. ¿I have insert a @click in <h1  @click="print">Print me!</h1> to make the capture? I have tried it but it's still failing

Comment: Then, I must can <h1 @click="print">Print me!</h1> ? @kb_

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/r4mbh6nu/ canvas example

vue konova https://codesandbox.io/s/github/konvajs/site/tree/master/vue-demos/basic_demo?from-embed